# GoogleMock: How to save a parameter to be used in the next call on the mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I try to mock the behaviour and API of an already existing class representing an NVRAM. The API is:

```
bool Init(Uint8* dataPointer); 
bool Store(); //Writes the data from dataPointer into the NVRAM
bool Restore(); //Writes the data from NVRAM into the dataPointer
```

My test scenario is the following:

1. Create `ClassUnderTest`, also calls the `Init` method
2. Call another Method in my `ClassUnderTest`, which calls the `Restore`-method. And I want to be able to control my mock in a way, that after the call on the `Restore`-method the value of the `dataPointer` is set.

Or in pseudo-code:

```
MockFoo foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Init(dataPointer)).WillOnce(Return(true));
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Restore()).WillOnce(DoAll(memcpy(dataPointer, testValues, sizeOf(testValues)), Return(true)));
```

What I have tried so far:

- Default actions from googleMock (e.g. SaveArg): Allows me to write data into the `dataPointer`, but only a the `Init`-call.
- Writing an ACTION_TEMPLATE to save the `dataPointer` in a lokal variable and then change its value, when `Restore` is called: As far as I unterstand I can only add VALUE_PARAMS to ACTION_TEMPLATEs, so I can hand values into the template, but have no way to hand them out again over some pointer.
- I looked at ActionInterface & Polymorphic Actions, if I understand the documentation correctly they have the same limitations as the ACTION_TEMPLATEs, regarding my problem.

In the end the main question for me is: 
Is there a way to save the `dataPointer` during the `Init`-call to be used later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I almost never use this `SaveArg`, `ACTION` or other small gmock features. I prefer to use `Invoke` and just define my own logic that should be invoked whenever call to the mocked method is executed. It might look like an overkill, but in fact very often is more readable and shorter:

```
class API {
public:
    virtual bool Init(uint8_t* dataPointer) = 0;
    virtual bool Store() = 0;
    virtual bool Restore() = 0;
};

class MockAPI : public API {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(Init,
      bool(uint8_t* dataPointer));
  MOCK_METHOD0(Store,
      bool());
  MOCK_METHOD0(Restore,
      bool());
};

class ClassUnderTest {
public:
    explicit ClassUnderTest(std::shared_ptr<API> api): api_(api) {
        dataPtr_ = new uint8_t;
        api_->Init(dataPtr_);
    }
    ~ClassUnderTest() {
        delete dataPtr_;
    }
    bool anotherMethod() {
        api_->Restore();
        return true;
    }
    uint8_t takeALookAtTheData() {
        return *dataPtr_;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<API> api_;
    uint8_t* dataPtr_;
};

using testing::_;
using testing::Invoke;

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    auto mockApi = std::make_shared<MockAPI>();
    uint8_t* dataPtr(nullptr);
    uint8_t testValue = 123;
    ON_CALL(*mockApi, Init(_)).WillByDefault(Invoke([&dataPtr](uint8_t* dataPointer) {
        dataPtr = dataPointer;
        return true;
    }));
    ON_CALL(*mockApi, Restore()).WillByDefault(Invoke([&dataPtr, testValue]() {
        *dataPtr = testValue;
        return true;
    }));
    ClassUnderTest sut(mockApi);
    ASSERT_NE(nullptr, dataPtr);
    sut.anotherMethod();
    ASSERT_EQ(testValue, *dataPtr);
    ASSERT_EQ(testValue, sut.takeALookAtTheData());
}
```

I hope I assumed correctly, that your system should allocate needed memory and your API is responsible for manipulating it. In any case, this should solve your problem.